# Validate e-mail as service

Tags: java, web-services, email, verify

Is there a way to validate an e-mail by consuming a service?
I have validate with "regex" the e-mail but I need verification for connection... I am using java in a web app and I need somelike this web does in my code:

```
www.ultratools.com/tools/emailTest
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of online services you can POST an email to which will evaluate it using their own criteria. The response to the call, you can use to determine if it is 'valid' or not.

Typically they check if the domain is valid, if there are mail servers on it, etc.